# SWRL - Rules depending on other rules assertions

Tags: owl, ontology, swrl

Currently I'm developing an ontology to represent preferences that a specific user may have about something. For example, the user may have an `MediaVolumeLevel` preference set to `VolumeLevel_3`.

The different levels (individuals of the class `MediaVolumeLevel`) are:
`VolumeLevel_1, VolumeLevel_2, VolumeLevel_3 and VolumeLevel_4`.

The user and the Preference are linked by the objectProperty `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference`.

The objectProperty assertion need to be inferred from other User aspects through SWRL rules. For example, if the user has a hearing difficulty, the `MediaVolumeLevel` needs to be set to `VolumeLevel_4.` So:

```
User(?u), hasDifficulty(?u,Hearing) -> hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(?u,VolumeLevel_4)
```

This is working fine. But, since I have other SWRL rules that also infer the `MediaVolumeLevel` for the same users, such as:

```
User(?u), hasContext(?u,NoisyRoom) -> hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(?u, VolumeLevel_3)
```

and SWRL supports monotonic inference only, the  reasoner will assert both VolumeLevels (`VolumeLevel_4` and `VolumeLevel_3`).

What I need is a rule that, somehow, will only assert the preference if there's no higher level already asserted. In the given example, even if `hasContext(?u,NoisyRoom)` is true, the only asserted level should be `VolumeLevel_4` because other rule asserted it.

Any advices on this? Is what I want possible using SWRL? 
I'm using Protege 4.3 and Pellet Reasoner

Thanks, MFV.

Answer (score 3):

this is possible but only in certain cases. Allow me to explain.

1) Your `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference` is an object property that relates to individuals`VolumeLevel_1, VolumeLevel_2, VolumeLevel_3 and VolumeLevel_4`. These individuals have no relative ordering in the ontology. You, as a human designer, are aware that `VolumeLevel_4` is greater than `VolumeLevel_3` but to a reasoner no such relative ordering exists. If you were to change `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference` to a data property with a range of `int` (or `long` or whatever really) then you have provided a concrete data value behind your individuals. Thus you can write rules using swrl comparison builtins, i.e `swrl:greaterThan` etc.

2) You can now write clauses into your rules that make comparisons in the antecedent so that only the highest value gets asserted, however SWRL supports monotonic inference only. Hence, SWRL rules cannot be used to modify existing information in an ontology. SWRL rules can not retract or remove information from an ontology. Therefore in the case where a lower volume, `Volume_3` gets asserted before `Volume_4`, you cannot remove the relation `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(Volume_3)` from your ontology. 

3) All is not lost yet though, Apache Jena has a rule engine that can be used to manipulate the ontology at an rdf triple level. You may have to write your own built-ins but you can remove properties and class descriptions from rdf subgraphs. Go [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#rules) for more info on Jena rules.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note, Jena rules cannot be placed directly in the ontology via xml syntax and have to be loaded from an external .txt file and fed to the Jena rules reasoner.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer @kunal-khaladkar

1) Ok, but what if no VolumeLevel has been already asserted? 

The rule:

`User(?u), hasDifficulty(?u,Hearing), hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(?vl), lessThan(?vl,4)  -> hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(?u,VolumeLevel_4)`

won't work because `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference(?vl)` is not true. Is there any workaround to solve this or am I getting it wrong? 

3) I've read the link about Jena and it seems very interesting.  Unfortunately, I've already wrote my sotware using OWL api and start coding again from scratch will take me too long

Comment: For 1) you are correct, that rule will not fire if `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference` is not asserted on an individual. As for a workaround, I can't really think of how that would actually look and behave. However, since you are using owl api, it may be better for you to allow multiple assertions of the `hasMediaVolumeLevelPreference` property and handle retrieving the "largest" one through your code. I'll continue to think on this problem though and let you know if I can come up with something.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing right now, but in my opinion it's a ugly solution. Having something in the ontology itself would be a much better approach. Thanks for your attention so far!